# Server references (not a database reference) in DB Projects

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I have an issue regarding a DB project in VS 2013. Where I am using, for example, `OPENQUERY([Server.IP],'blah blah')`, the server name will always return a warning. E.g.

> "Procedure [dbo].[xxx] has an unresolved reference to object [server.IP]".

Is it possible to remove these errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the linked server in your project.

Just add a New Item of Linked Server type to your project and then put the linked server definition in it. For example:

```
/****** Object:  LinkedServer [Server.IP]    Script Date: 30/07/2014 16:17:56 ******/
EXEC dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'Server.IP', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
GO
 /* For security reasons the linked server remote logins password is changed with ######## */
EXEC dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```